# Adding or removing a text field depending on pick list value

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I am very recent to salesforce.com so i don't have much idea about it. I have a requirement in which requires that a text field be created or removed depending on a pick list value.
For example I have 2 fields "Issues" and "Comments". according to the requirement when if i choose the value 'others' then the field "Comments" Should be visible, otherwise the field should be removed.
I don't think the above scenarios can be accomplished by using Formula Editor or Validations. Is there any way in which the above mentioned can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question directly to do with doing this is Salesforce1, or for communities? Or is this just a standard salesforce UI feature you want to do this with?

Comment: I am using a developer version of the salesforce.com.

Answer (score 1):

This cant be done on standard page. You have to go through VF page to implement custom logic.

Comment: Are u saying that i should create a "custom Visualforce tab" and then add a VF page with a logic? In that case i will have to start the page from scratch for just this one requirement??

Comment: This link might help you using home page component.             http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/